# Date and Time Format Conversion in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 sp1 .I have a table column with the following Date Time values.

```
BLDCHKDT
-----------------------
2013-06-19 00:00:00.000
2013-07-22 00:00:00.000
2013-08-21 00:00:00.000
2013-09-20 00:00:00.000
2013-11-18 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to retrieve the date and Time in the following formats:

```
Date: 19062013
Time: 00000000
```

Is it possible? I have reviewed the SQL Server help documentation for the FORMAT, CAST and CONVERT functions and I can’t seem to get any headway.
So far I have attempted the following conversions:

*N.B Please note that I am converting to Date time to string to facilitate a flat file export.*

--Retrieving Date

```
SELECT [DATE-BLDCHKD] = CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), BLDCHKDT, 112)
FROM TABLEA

DATE-BLDCHKD
--------------------
20130619
20130722
20130821
20130920
20131118

--Retrieving Time
SELECT [TIME-BLDCHKD] = CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), BLDCHKDT, 24)
FROM TABLEA

TIME-BLDCHKD
--------------------
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

I appreciate your insights. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just curious, how does conversion to a non-standard date format facilitate a flat-file export?

Comment: I just saw this Hart Co. I was converting records to Banking ACH format.Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
declare @value datetime = getdate()

select 
    replace(convert(varchar(20), @value, 104), '.', '') date_part,
    left(replace(convert(varchar(20), @value, 114), ':', ''), 8) time_part
```

returns 23032014, 17174466 for 2014-03-23 17:17:44.660

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using SQL Server 2012 you can use the `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(BLDCHKDT,'ddMMyyyy')
     , FORMAT(BLDCHKDT,'hhmmssfff')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 104th format for date part:

```
select replace (convert (varchar(10), @value, 104), '.', '') as date_part
```